# List of tables and columns used by SSRS Reports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler, sql-trace

I have a number of SSRS reports that extract data from a SQL Server database via a stored procedure. I wanted to know what tables are used by each report/stored procedure in the following format:

| SP Name | Table | Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SP1 | tblOrder | ID |
| SP1 | tblOrder | Volume |
| SP2 | tblCust | Name |

ie: if a stored procedure uses 2 columns, there will be 2 rows.

Is there a SQL tool I can use to achieve this? SQL Profile/Trace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out expression_dependencies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16